# Notion to Gitlab migration

Tags: gitlab, storyboard, product, backlog, notion

I have done all the backlog for tracking bugs, features, storys in Notion and now I have reached a point where I would like to migrate all my Notion items into Gitlab.

I have already seen that I can easily add gitlab MR and etc links into notion tickets via /gitlab.

However, this is not what I am looking for. I am looking for a way to migrate the complete backlog into Gitlab or to have them synced.

What would be the best way to do it?

Tried so far: Notion integration with Gitlab. /gitlab. read some documentation etc.